# ASP.Net asynch operations

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous

Using a Generic Handler, I'd like to 2 do things in parallel.  First, I need to send a request to a 3rd part and get the result back (this can take up to 25 seconds) and while that is happening, parse some XML and insert a record into a database.

How would I go about issuing an Http request (like GetResponse()) but not have it pause until it gets a response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Create an asynchronous HTTP handler class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227433.aspx). In your `BeginProcessRequest`, you can create [two tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx), one for the 3rd party request, one for the XML parse and then run them in parallel. [Here's a pretty good tutorial](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=491) that shows how to define tasks that return values and run them in parallel.

Comment: Thank you for that.  Works great.  I'm going to ask another question soon, basically asking about thread safety and how to do this a couple thousand times a second.  I hope you see it, too.

Comment: Great - so did I answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is creating a web service class in your project and having the web service do the work for the 3rd party request. Methods in a web service can be called asynchronously, so you can create a method in the service, reference the service from your page, then use the asynchronous overload of the method.